# Google Sheets scripting, adding day to dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've looked at other questions on this, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I have an array which my code loops through, and part of the array it needs to add a day to one of the dates. my code (with loggers to show the data) looks like this:

```
  Logger.log('source array - ' + sourceArray[i][8])      
  var deliveryDate = new Date(sourceArray[i][8])
  Logger.log ('deliveryDate - ' + deliveryDate)
  var newDate = new Date(deliveryDate + 1000*60*60*24)
  Logger.log ('newDate - ' + newDate)
```

There's more to my application but this is where I'm having issues.

This is a screenshot of the log
[image]

As you can see the data from the source array has a date of 8th march 2023

So does the deliveryDate variable that I assign the data to.

But after adding to it (I read to use that multiplication to add a day)
newDate is still the same.

I can't figure out where my syntax is wrong.

Comment: From your showing log, I guess that the value of `sourceArray[i][8]` is a date object. If my understanding is correct, `deliveryDate` is a date object. And, at `var newDate = new Date(deliveryDate + 1000*60*60*24)`, `1000*60*60*24` is added to the date object. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about modifying `var newDate = new Date(deliveryDate + 1000*60*60*24)` to `var newDate = new Date(deliveryDate.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addADay(dt = new Date()) {
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  Logger.log(dt);
}
```

Comment: that seems to just add a day to the current date, I want to add to my date

Comment: it depends upon what date you pass to it.  dt is a parameter which is currently given a default value.  You might wish to read a little about parameters and default parameters in your favorite javascript documentatin